# Separating my data to groups and combining them

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, group-by

I have a dataframe with data with  2 variables that have values from 0 to 1000. How can I efficiently split it into groups? I want to split x to 10 groups (0 to 100, 100 to 200 ... 900 to 1000 etc.) and then do the same thing for y (0 to 100, 100 to 200 ... 900 to 1000 etc.). And then I want to combine them and have every single combination. One group having 0

Example data

```
x          y

102        602

224        340

368        756

487        305

568        310

510        911

10         50

340        519

9          282

10         150
```

Comment: Can you please add example output as well.

Comment: I want to split each variable in groups and then combine these groups in all ways possible. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to split them into groups of 10 remember that from 0 to 1000 we have 1001 numbers so the groups would be something like: 0 - 100, 101 - 200, 201 - 300,.....,901 - 1000. you will have 9 groups of 100 elements and 1 group of 101 elements. If you do the groups like your idea you will have ten groups of 101 elements each one beacuse you are repeating some numbers. So I don't know how you want to distribute the groups so Im going to work with 0 to 999 to have 10 groups of 100 elements each one. The possible permutations for the groups are 10x10 = 100 but if you want the permutations of the the elements as well it would be a huge number 100x100 = 10,000 x 100 = 1,000,000. So first you need to explain if you want the permutations of the groups only or you want to combine the elements as well. I don't know if you are using pandas so I'm going to give you the logic with pure Python.

To split x and y into groups of ten with the numbers from 0 to 999 you can do something like this:

```
x_group_list = [[i for i in range(k * 100,(k + 1)*100)] for k in range(0,10)]
y_group_list = [[i for i in range(k * 100,(k + 1)*100)] for k in range(0,10)]
```